# Material date picker dialog in tablayout and viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

Hello everyone i am developing one app i am new to android so i managed to develop navigation drawer and tablayout within it.and its work fine but the main problem is that i want to dispaly material datepicker Dialog in specfic tab when user click on edittext text

But datepicker is not working it gives

```
cannot resolve method show(android.support.v4.app.feagmentManager,String)
on the following line

 dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Follow Date");
```

Following is my Fragment code

```
 import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;

 import java.util.Calendar;


 public class OneFragment extends Fragment implement DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
EditText nxt_followup;
Context mContext;

public OneFragment() {
    mContext=getActivity();
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    nxt_followup=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.nextfollowup);
    nxt_followup.setClickable(true);
    nxt_followup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            //display date picker dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    OneFragment.this,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),//current year
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),//current month
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)//current date
            );
            dpd.setMinDate(now);

            //set the theme
            dpd.setThemeDark(false);
            //vibrate on open
            dpd.vibrate(true);
            dpd.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4081"));
            dpd.dismissOnPause(false);
            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Follow Date");
        }
        });

    return view;
}



@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

}

 }
```

I want to dispaly material datepickerdialog when user click on edittext from first tab which conatin edittext
And the code of implementing viewpager and fragment is as follows

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Gift");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Album");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "History");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Please help me to display Material datepickerDialog.On internet i am not getting solution

How to display Material dialog in Tablayout which contain fragment and within that fragment i want to displat material date picker dialog

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line of code

```
dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Follow Date");
```